# I am trying to connect to JMX with authentication using jconsole, but I am not able to do so. But I am able to connect it without authentication

Tags: java, jmx, tomcat8

I have set this as `java_opts`

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$TOMCAT_DIR/conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$TOMCAT_DIR/conf/jmxremote.access  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$APP_SERVER_HOSTNAME"
```

in tomcat.

I am able to connect using jconsole without any authentication, if `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate` is set as false. But, with authentication as true, I am not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password?

For example:

```
$ vi $TOMCAT_DIR/conf/jmxremote.access
# Add "admin" account permission as follows:
admin         readwrite \
              create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \
              unregister

$ vi $TOMCAT_DIR/conf/jmxremote.password
# Add "admin" account password as follows:
admin password
```